# Pass templated function as attachInterrupt parameter

Tags: c++, interrupt

So I want to do something like this:

```
template<int PIN, int CHANNEL>
void initPin() {
    attachInterrupt(PIN, rising<PIN, CHANNEL>, RISING);
}


template<int PIN, int CHANNEL>
void rising() {
    startTimes[CHANNEL] = micros();
    attachInterrupt(PIN, falling<PIN, CHANNEL>, FALLING);
}

template<int PIN, int CHANNEL>
void falling() {
    values[CHANNEL] = micros() - startTimes[CHANNEL];
    attachInterrupt(PIN, rising<PIN, CHANNEL>, RISING);
}
```

but the compiler gives me this error

```
no matches converting function ‘rising’ to type ‘void (*)()’
```

Can I even do this, or do I have to write all the functions by myself?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
template<int PIN, int CHANNEL> void initPin() {
    attachInterrupt(PIN, rising<PIN, CHANNEL>, RISING);
}


template<int PIN, int CHANNEL> void rising() {
    startTimes[CHANNEL] = micros();
    attachInterrupt(PIN, falling<PIN, CHANNEL>, FALLING);
}

template<int PIN, int CHANNEL> void falling() {
    values[CHANNEL] = micros() - startTimes[CHANNEL];
    attachInterrupt(PIN, rising<PIN, CHANNEL>, RISING);
}
```

The problem is actually the Arduino preprocessor. It adds illegal forward declarations if template functions are formated as your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look implementation 
https://github.com/Yurik72/SimpleButton

There are implementation how to assign function with arguments to interrupt handler